# Global Custom Authorize Attribute with Excluded Atrribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization, action-filter, authorize-attribute

I have two attributes :

```
public class AnonymousAllowedAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute { }

public class ActionAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute { 

  public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {

    bool skipAuthorization =
        filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AnonymousAllowedAttribute), true)
        ||
        filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AnonymousAllowedAttribute), true);
        if(!skipAuthorization)
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
  }


  bool CustomeCheck() {
    bool result = //My Checks
    return result;
   }
}
```

I define `ActionAuthorizeAttribute` as a global attribute.

So I need this 3 items:

1- If did not log in(`!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`): Go to LogIn Page `Accounts/LogIn`.
I must mention the `LogIn` action marked with `AnonymousAllowedAttribute`.

2- If log in (`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`) and action or controller have `AnonymousAllowedAttribute` then authorize is true (don't need any authorization).

3- If log in (`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`) and action haven't `AnonymousAllowedAttribute` return `CustomeCheck()` method

I try second one by override `OnAuthorization()` method as you see.

and third one by followings:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext){
   if(!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      return false;

   return CustomeCheck();
}
```

but when I did not log in always return:

IIS 7.5 Error Details:

HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized

with this URL: `http://myProject/Accounts/LogIn?ReturnUrl=%2f`

where is the problem? how can implement `ActionAuthorizeAttribute` to achieve this 3 goals?

**Update**

I find answer : the problem is the : `AnonymousAllowedAttribute` need to inherit from `Attribute` rather than `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is: The  `AnonymousAllowedAttribute` need to inherit from `Attribute` rather than `AuthorizeAttribute`.

when `AnonymousAllowedAttribute` inherit from `AuthorizeAttribute` so need to authorize but I create that to reduce Authorization!!